# Break Point on HTML DOM in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

There is a simple problem: I have to find out Javascript code which is changing page HTML when document is being ready.
I have tried Google Chrome Debugging tool to put break point at DOM as guided in this [link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/add-breakpoints?hl=en).  But it didn't worked for me because Google Chrome HTML Debugger works after page is ready.  So it didn't worked for me.

Is there any tool which can place debugger on HTML and can work when page is being ready and loaded on the browser?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: Add <script>debugger;</script> [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_debugger.asp)

Comment: Also you read this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/add-breakpoints?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You can put `debugger;` in your javascript code to cause the code to pause.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_debugger.asp

Comment: I have to find javascript, which is my problem

Comment: you could add `<script>debugger;</script>` somewhere in your html and go from there.

Comment: As suggsted by @Wout De Rooms , you can place debugger at the top of your script. <script>debugger;</script>. Then refresh the page. This will stop at the debugger line. Then keep pressing f10 and execute line one by one. If your html changes after pressing f10 then you know that line is responsible for the html change.

Comment: yes i have tried this, but my project is too large and it 9 jquery plugins and 4 custom javascript files :(

Answer (score 0):

Add a `debugger;` statement to the entry point of your app or somewhere early on. That way, the debugger will pause before it has parsed your code and generated the DOM.

Comment: yes i have tried this, but my project is too large and it 9 jquery plugins and 4 custom javascript files :(

Comment: @Numan Ali If you don't want to spend time working out the entry point, just place a `debugger;` statement at the top of the JS files and HTML page (if there's inline code).